# Gnuplot tic frequency

Tags: bash, gnuplot

For a very large data-set, how can gnuplot be used to only put tic marks/labels on the x axis for just the first and last data point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gnuplot 4.6 and up, you can use the commands

```
stats 'data.dat'
set xtics \
 (sprintf("%.2g",STATS_min_x) STATS_min_x, \
  sprintf("%.2g",STATS_max_x) STATS_max_x)
plot 'data.dat'
```

With other versions of gnuplot, you can use this similar sequence of commands:

```
# this setting makes sure we don't make an output right away
set terminal unknown
plot 'data.dat'
set xtics \
 (sprintf("%.2g",GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN) GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN, \
  sprintf("%.2g",GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX) GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX)
set terminal <actual terminal>
replot
```

The `set xtics` command takes comma-separated pairs of strings with data values, all inside parentheses.

(Here I assume you want the minimum and maximum, not the first and last, data points.)

For more info you can run these at the gnuplot command line:

`help set format`

`help set stats`

`show variables all`

Comment: No I would like the first and the last (not min/max)

Comment: Pardon me for the irrelevant answer then.  I think I can cook up an answer to your actual question, though it'll be a little trickier.  Which version of gnuplot do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer because my other one really answered a different question, but may be useful.  To answer the question,

**How to mark the x tics for the first and last data points**?

here is my method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal png
set output 'test.png'

# define a function to get the first and last values.
# this assumes the file has not changed since first running 'stats',
# (and contains at least one data point)
# `plot/stats 'data.dat' using (firstlast($x))`
# should be interchangable with
# `plot/stats 'data.dat' using x
# that is, the resulting variables should be the same
firstlast(x) = ($0==0) ? (first=$1, last=$1, $1) : (last=$1, $1)

# run stats  to find the first and last values
# just on x data column
stats 'data.dat' u (firstlast($1)) nooutput

# set the x tics to the first and last x points
set xtics \
 (sprintf("%.2g (first)", first) first, \
  sprintf("%.2g (last)", last) last)

print first
print last

plot 'data.dat'
```

I used this example data file:

### data.dat

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 2
0 3
```

and got this output:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you could do this a little more concisely:  `firstlast(x) = ($0==0) ? (first=$1, $1) : (last=$1, $1)` -- Then you could use this function in your first `stats` command which would remove the need to have the second stats command.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way around running `stats` twice, which I did not like.

Comment: The only catch is that you need to plot more than 1 point (otherwise, `last` will not be defined), but that's easy enough to check for:  `if (!exists("last")) last=first`, or you could modify firstlast slightly:  `firstlast(x) = ($0==0)? (first=$1,last=$1,$1) : (last=$1,$1)`