# Limit the number of ytics while using automatic ytics placement

Tags: gnuplot

I wrote a bash script that generates files that are then plotted automatically using the following template (minimal working example):

```
 set terminal epslatex color size 3,1.2
 set output "fig.tex"

 set ylabel '$\lambda_i$' offset +1.5,0
 set xlabel '$i$' offset 0,+0.5
 set logscale x
 set mxtics 5
 set mytics 5
 plot "file.dat"  w p pt 7 ps 0.7 lc rgb "#033775"
```

Everything works just fine, but there tends to be too many ytics when the inputed data spans an appreciable range of value.

[Not enough rep, so here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd7XK.png]

I suspect that  the epslatex terminal is causing the problems (i.e. gnuplot is not aware of the real font height and scrams too many tics in the available space).  My workaround would be to limit the number of tics, while allowing automatic ytics placement, but I cannot find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can reduce the frequency of tics on the y axis with

```
set ytics VALUE
```

An example would be:

```
plot sin(x)
```

produces this the automatic tics (fix: image link removed)
and

```
set ytics 0.5
plot sin(x)
```

produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ch3L.jpg).

If you do not know which value to put for VALUE, you can calculate this by using STATS_min_x and STATS_max_x for gnuplot4.6 and GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN for earlier versions. For usage of those see i.e. [the answer from andyras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14129716/1834164)

Alternatively (with similar usage) it might be more useful in this case to use GPVAL_Y_MIN and GPVAL_Y_MAX instead, as they are already rounded.

Then you can use for example:

```
set terminal unknown
plot(x)
ntics = 4.
dy = floor((GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN+0.5)/ntics*10.)/10.
set ytics dy
set terminal ...
replot
```

which produces for the example above the 4 tics as specified (fix: link to image removed).

Comment: note that OP is using a logarithmic axis, so the interpretation of VALUE in this case is *slightly* different.  Otherwise, I think this is the best you can do.  +1

Comment: Thank you! I already stumbled onto such solutions, though. It works well with most terminals (e.g. eps), but epslatex does not play well with replot.. it tends to produce messed up .tex documents! I guess I'll have to dig into that :)