# Limit the number of ytics and keep mytics when using logscale

Tags: gnuplot

This question is somewhat similar to [Limit the number of ytics while using automatic ytics placement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15668178) but doesn't get answered in that thread.

I used the following code to generate my graph gnuplot:

```
set yrange[.125:512]
set logscale y 2
set ytics 2
set mytics 16
set grid mytics ytics 
set key off
plot '20131019_square.log' using 2:xticlabels(1) with linespoints linestyle 2
```

resulting in graph_1. (post it in comment because this is my first post <10 rep)

I find the ytics somewhat dense, so I change `set ytics 2` to `set ytics 8`
resulting in [graph_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S58Dd.png)

In this second graph the spacing is fine, but mytics behaves incorrect (I need logspacing) and the tics numbering I really want to use is (.03125,0.125,.5,2,8,32,128,512) what I can obtain using `set ytics to (.03125,0.125,.5,2,8,32,128,512)`
resulting in [graph_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xspXH.png)

Everything is correct in the last one, but I'll lose my minor ytics. (This is normal behavior for gnuplot, but I would like to get the tics of this graph_3.)

Any ideas on how to get graph_3 **with** mytics?

Comment: Graph 1: http://i.imgur.com/k0Fq1x3.png

Answer (score 0):

You can have minor tics only for automatically generated major tics like you get with:

```
set ytics 0.03125,4
```

With `logscale` set, the increment (here `4`) is treated as a multiplier for the starting value (here `0.03125`).

A full, minimal script would then be

```
set logscale y 2
set yrange[0.03125:512]
set ytics 0.03125,4
set mytics
set xrange[0:10]
plot x
```

Comment: Thanks for the minimal script Christoph, the scale is indeed correct now, but now all mytics are still equally spaced: [plot](http://i.imgur.com/Rr6lWSS.png). I need them with logspacing to recognize this graph as logarithmic in the blink of an eye.

Comment: Yes, you are right, haven't noticed that. I don't know how to fix that.