# Round ytics to nearest ten

Tags: gnuplot

I want to create a bar chart with gnuplot where I have exactly 5 tics on the y axis. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672082/8779724) answer to do this. However, I get very exact numbers on the ytics when I do this. By doing `set ytics format "%.0f"`, I can round the values to the nearest number. However, I want to round these numbers again to the next ten as well. So when I get the value 91.7 on the y-axis, it should instead make a tic at 90 or 100.

Is there a possibility to do this in gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same spacing between all ticks, you could just adapt the answer you link to by changing the two operations involving the factor 10:

```
dy = floor((GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/(ntics*10.))*10
```

Answer (score 0):

"set ytics 10" will give one tic every 10 units over whatever range is relevant.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I want. If I have values between 1000 and 5000 and just want 3 tics on the y-axis, this doesn't work.